# How to print negative zero in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am converting decimal degrees to print as DMS.  The conversion algorithm is what you would expect, using modf, with the addition that sign is taken out of the MS portion and left in only for the D portion.

Everything is fine except for the case where the Degree is negative zero, -0.  An example is -0.391612 which should print as -0°23'29".

"%d" drops the negative sign.  What format string can I use to print -0?

I've worked around it with a kludge that converts the numbers to strings and prepends a "-" if negative, then uses "%s" as the format.  It's awkward and feels inelegant.

Here's the code:

```
def dec_to_DMS(decimal_deg):
  deg = modf(decimal_deg)[1]
  deg_ = fabs(modf(decimal_deg)[0])
  min = modf(deg_ * 60)[1]
  min_ = modf(deg_ * 60)[0]
  sec = modf(min_ * 60)[1]
  return deg,min,sec

def print_DMS(dms):         # dms is a tuple
  # make sure the "-" is printed for -0.xxx
  format = ("-" if copysign(1,dms[0]) < 0 else "") + "%d°%02d'%02d\""
  return format % dms

print print_DMS(dec_to_DMS(-0.391612))
>>> -0°23'29"
```

`deg_` is to prevent the function returning (-0,-23,-29); it returns the correct (-0,23,29).

Comment: Please show a minimal example code for the problem.

Comment: +1 because using `modf` should make the whole thing quite elegant

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `format()`

```
>>> format(-0.0)
'-0.0'
>>> format(0.0)
'0.0'


>>> print '''{: g}°{}'{}"'''.format(-0.0, 23, 29)
-0°23'29"
```

Comment: It's too bad that so many tutorial/how-to websites still advocate using the old `%` notation instead of `format`.  This is a perfect example of why it is important to switch.  Good one!

Comment: @gnibbler Thanks, that nailed it. Note that the tuple needs to be expanded with `*`, since format() expects the number of arguments to be the same as the number of {}'s in the format string: `'''{: g}°{:02.0f}'{:02.0f}"'''.format(*dms)`

Answer (score 2):

You must print the degrees as a floating point value, not as an integer, as 2 complement integers (used on most platforms) do not have a negative zero. `%d` is for formatting integers.

```
print u'{:.0f}°{:.0f}\'{:.0f}\"'.format(deg, fabs(min), fabs(sec)).encode('utf-8')
```

`deg`, `min` and `sec` are all floats, the `fabs` calls are there so that the respective signs are not printed.

Alternatively using the old format string style:

```
print (u'%.0f°%.0f\'%.0f\"' % (deg, fabs(min), fabs(sec))).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Why not just use `%g` instead of `%.0f`?

Comment: Because `%g` may choose to use an exponential format variant depending on the value passed which in this case results in `-0°2e+01'3e+01"` (on my platform) which is definitely not what you would want. `%f` ensures that a non-exponential format is used.